# Ciclo while no termina python

Tags: python, while

Estoy realizando un codigo que recibe 2 numeros, y verifica que los digitos del numero 1 sean los mismos en el numero 2, de ser asi retorna True, y en caso contrario resulta False, la parte que verifica si esa parte la realice con el ciclo while y la ayuda de un contador para que esto fuera un ciclo finito(pudiera usar for, pero no es lo que me piden), pero cuando uso el ciclo while y ejecuto pareciera que el ciclo while no termina, espero darme a entender, igual adjunto mi codigo. Ojala pudieran ayudarme.

```
def mismos_digitos(a,b):
lista_a=[]
lista_b=[]
c=len(str(a))
d=len(str(b))
for i in range(c):
    p=a//10
    lista_a.append(a%10)
    a=p
for i in range(d):
    q=b//10
    lista_b.append(b%10)
    b=q
centinel=True
contador_a=0
# a en b
while contador_a<len(lista_a):
    if lista_a[contador_a] in lista_b:
        contador_a=contador_a+1
        continue
    else:
        centinel=False
        
# b en a
contador_b=0
while contador_b<len(lista_b):
    if lista_b[contador_b] in lista_a:
        contador_b=contador_b+1
        continue
    else:
        centinel=False
        

return centinel
```

print(mismos_digitos(11,12345))

Comment: Tal como están hechos tus whiles, si un elemento de lista a no está en la b, el contador no incrementa, y como el contador define la posicion del item a obtener, vuelve a buscar, claramente sin exito. No incrementa, vuelve a buscar el mismo elemento, sin exito. No aumenta el contador. Mientras tanto, como el contador no incrementa, este siempre será menor al largo de la lista, dando siempre true. Creaste un bucle infinito.

Comment: Para salir de eso, el contador debe incrementar siempre. Simplemente, ponlo al final del bucle, fuera de los condicionales, y elimina el continue. Continue dice, "no ejecutes el código que sigue y volvé al principio del while"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El **while** no se detiene porque la condición que declaró está agregando un elemento a la lista `lista_a` en cada iteración del bucle:

En esta parte que está agregando:

```
def mismos_digitos(a, b):
    lista_a = []
    lista_b = []
    c = len(str(a))
    d = len(str(b))
    for i in range(c):
        p = a // 10
        # Añade un elemento a la lista .
        lista_a.append(a % 10)
        a = p
```

La lista `lista_a` está añadiendo un elemento a la lista en cada iteración del bucle.

*-* Para que el bucle siga ejecutándose y termine el ciclo, utiliza el operador lógico **and**, que devolverá True si ambas expresiones son verdaderas: si `lista_a` todavía tiene elementos y el valor actual de la lista está contenido en la lista.

Este fragmento del código que necesita corregir.

```
while contador_a<len(lista_a):
    if lista_a[contador_a] in lista_b:
        contador_a=contador_a+1
        continue
    else:
        centinel=False
```

De esta manera

```
while contador_a < len(lista_a) and lista_a[contador_a] in lista_b:
    contador_a = contador_a + 1
    continue
else:
    centinel = False
```

Esa parte también

```
 while contador_b < len(lista_b) and lista_b[contador_b] in lista_a:
        contador_b = contador_b + 1
        continue
    else:
        centinel = False
```

Esta corrección hace que el **while** realice las iteraciones de manera correcta, si una o ambas condiciones son **falsas**, el bucle se **detendrá**.

El operador [*END*](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/operator.html) en el código opera con dos expresiones **unidimensionales** que están comparando valores **individuales**.

Comment: El bucle for no es infinito, el contador interno tiene su limite establecido en el largo de la lista antes de que se ejecute el bucle for. Esto se debe a que en realidad no está iterando la lista, si no al objeto range.

Comment: No dije que el loop es infinito en ninguna parte de mi explicación; afirmo que la condición del loop while siempre será verdadera porque la lista siempre tendrá un elemento adicional. El uso del "and" garantizará que el loop solo continuará si ambas condiciones son satisfechas. Tu respuesta también es correcta y resuelve el tema de la pregunta del usuario.

Comment: Gracias! Sin embargo, en los whiles no se agrega ningún elemento

Comment: El while siempre será verdadero **PORQUE** en la lista `lista_a` siempre habrá un elemento.

Comment: Ohhh, ya entendí. Creo que ambos nos enfocamos en el mismo problema. Sin embargo, tu respuesta dice "La lista lista_a está añadiendo un elemento a la lista en cada iteración del bucle"